# Image not taking up entire width of <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and within that table is an image.  The image isn't taking up the entire height and width of the row that is is located in.  I have set the img to 100% width and heigh, but nothing works.  Below is my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        background-color: #c1b7a6;
        width: 40%;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
    }
    .style2
    {
        background-color:#7f6d53;
        width: 40%;
        padding-left: 1.5em;



    }
    .style3
    {
        background-color:#5e513d;
        width: 40%;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
      }
      .style4
      {
          outline: #5c492d solid 2px;             
          width: 100%;
      }
          .style5
          {
              border-right: 2px solid #5c492d;

        }
        .style6
        {
            padding-left: 1.5em;
        }
        .style7
        {
            background-color: #7f6d53;
            outline: #5c492d solid 2px;
        }
        .style8
        {
           width:100%;
           height: 100%;
           display: block;
        }
        .img
        {
           height:100%;
        width: 100%;


     } 

     </style>

      <div align="center" >
    <table class="style4" cellpadding= "0px" cellspacing= "0px">

      <tr>
     <td rowspan="3" align="left" valign="top" class="style5" >
     <img id="imgMain" src="Images/Logo" class="img" />

    </td>

    <td   align="left" valign="top" class="style1">  <asp:Image ID="imgText" runat="server" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td  align="left" valign="top" class="style2" ><asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server"  Text="Label" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  align="left" valign="top" class="style3"> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"    Text="Refine Your Results By" 
                  Font-Names="KozGoPr6n-Bold" ForeColor="#F9B92D"></asp:Label>
              <br />


          &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </td>
  </tr>

    </table>
```

Any suggestions are apprecitated!

Comment: You have set `padding` to the cells.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your image may be getting set to a specific width by the ASP code. Try using !important:

```
.img
    {
        height:100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```

Comment: Because using `!important` should be avoided. It is due to another problem that can be fixed, not overridden with `!important`

Comment: True enough, the problem should be fixed in ASP code, which I know nothing about. That's just a quick and dirty CSS fix.

Answer (score 0):

try things such as:

```
table td {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
table {border-spacing: 0px;}
```

and:

```
img {display: block;}
img {vertical-align: bottom;}
```

(This is because of margins/fill with different browsers)

Sorry, I found your question hard to read, and style by numbers lost me completely! But the above has worked for me in similar solutions in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting image border to none.